# Asp Mvc post add item to list

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I start learning asp net. I want show List in table and create new row on this page

i create model

```
  public class Student
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }

}
```

Then view

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication1.Models.Student>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Surname)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Surname)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>


<div class="form-horizontal">
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-2">Имя</label>
            @Html.TextBox("name", null, new {@class = "form-control col-lg-4"})
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-2">Фамилия</label>
            @Html.TextBox("surname", null, new {@class = "form-control col-lg-4"})
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Добавить</button>
    }
</div>

<div class="panel-footer">
    <h3>@ViewBag.Msg</h3>
</div>
```

And Controller

```
  List<Student> Students=new List<Student>
    {
        new Student() {Name = "1",Surname = "1"},
        new Student() {Name = "2",Surname = "2"},
        new Student() {Name = "3",Surname = "3"}
    }; 
    // GET: Home
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(Students);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(string name,string surname)
    {
        Students.Add(new Student() {Name = name,Surname = surname});
        @ViewBag.Msg = "User add : " + name +" "+ surname;
        return View(Students);
    }
```

All work good but when i add new row last row recreate(add only one row in my collection). Where i was wrong? sorry for my bad english

Comment: i want press button and add row in my table

Answer (score 3):

The list is a private variable of the controller class, because on each request for the page, a new instance of the controller will be created, the list items will be initialized each time with their initial values, and then just the new value will be added to it.
You can define the list as static to prevent initialization on each request:

```
static List<Student> Students=new List<Student>
{
    new Student() {Name = "1",Surname = "1"},
    new Student() {Name = "2",Surname = "2"},
    new Student() {Name = "3",Surname = "3"}
};
```

Comment: @user3351644, Redirect back to the `Index()` method.

Answer (score 1):

You're not persisting your data anywhere, so it's going to reset with every request.  This property:

```
List<Student> Students
```

is a class-level property.  It gets initialized any time an instance of the class is created.  And an instance of the controller class is created for each individual request made to the server.  So what's happening here is:

1. User requests the page
2. Controller object is created, initialized the list
3. Controller returns list to user
4. User posts new item
5. Controller object is created, initialized the list
6. Controller adds 4th item to the list
7. Controller returns list to user

Steps 4-7 repeat on every post.

In order to retain your data, you need to store it somewhere.  A database is ideal.  But there are other options, depending on the scope of what you're doing.

For example, just to test the functionality, you could store it in session state.  In that case it'll be reset for each user session, rather than for each request.

Or perhaps you can make the list `static`, in which case it would be used across the entire application instance for all users.  (But would *not* be thread-safe.)